# Firebase query of subsequent data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For angular firebase project, I have following query for data:

**Data:**
[image]

...where it is stored from old to new (or 1 to 4)

Then, I have following to retrieve it:

```
var startHere = '-KtOLj2ay8S0LHYBzQ2L'; // #3
this.firedata.child('/01_Total').startAt(startHere).limitToLast(2).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        var data = snapshot.val();             
})
```

In this case, I am trying to retrieve #1 and #2 (or those after #3).

I am getting an error of uncaught promise.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `startAt` you need to indicate what to order the data on first:

```
this.firedata.child('/01_Total').orderByKey().startAt(startHere).limitToLast(2)
```

Comment: Ah,, i see. That makes sense. Thanks for the help all the time! =)

Comment: Just another quick question. I noticed that `startAt` is inclusive (meaning, I am getting #1,2 and #3 which is the `startHere` value). How would I go about to exclude the `startHere` value from returning (thus only #1 and #2). Thanks.

Comment: As you've discovered, the filters are inclusive. So the only option is to exclude the overlapping item (often called the "anchor item") in your client-side code.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Frank! Appreciate it!